# Simple key search in php array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have a simple multidimensional array, like so:

```
$arr1 = array(3,5,array(4,"foo", array("bar","qux"=>"id")));
```

Then the recursive function,

```
function getVal($arr){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
      if($key=="qux"){
        echo $val."<br>";
      }elseif(is_array($val)){
        getVal($val);
      }
    }
}
```

Then finally, calling the function for the first time

```
getVal($arr1);
```

However, it outputs

```
3
4
bar
id
```

As opposed to only "id". Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Try `$key === "qux"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your keys are numbers, which means you're doing `0 == 'qux'`, which in PHP-land evaluates to `true` (qux gets converted to integer 0, and obviously 0==0 is true). You need to use `===`, which compares value **AND** type.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Thanks for the explanation!
Have to wait 9 minutes to accept the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(3,5,array(4,"foo", array("bar","qux"=>"id")));
function getVal($arr){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
      if($key==="qux"){
        echo $val."<br>";
      }elseif(is_array($val)){
        getVal($val);
      }
    }
}
getVal($arr1);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Manikiran. I'll select @Marc B's answer though because of the explaination.

Comment: No worries, I am still a beginner trying to improve my skills.